# Is the closure of the region bounded by a piecewise $C^1$ Jordan curve $C^1$-diffeomorphic to a polygon?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, plane-curves, greens-theorem

Given a piecewise $C^1$ Jordan curve $\sigma$, there is a region $A$ bounded by $\sigma$. **Is it true that $\overline A$ is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to a closed polygon?**  (I believe this is the same as claiming $\overline A$ has a $C^1$ triangulation.)

A curve $\phi: [0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ is said to be piecewise $C^1$ if there exist finitely many $a_i$ that $0 = a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_{n-1} < a_n = 1$, and $\phi$ is $C^1$ on each $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$.

The claim holds if $\sigma$ is $C^1$ (not just piecewise $C^1$) as is shown in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853883/smooth-jordan-sch%C3%B6nflies-curve-theorem).

I am looking for a rigorous proof of Green's theorem which is said to hold for piecewise $C^1$ Jordan curves.

Comment: Please, add your definition of a piecewise $C^1$ curve.

Comment: OK, I have edited the question.

Comment: Then the claim is false.

Comment: OK, is there any reference or counterexample? Is it still false if the direction of one-sided limits of $\frac {d\phi} {dt}$ at $a_i$ are not opposite?

Comment: An example would be a curve which contains a small neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $\{(x,y): x^2=y^3\}$. But if you make the assumption about derivative as in your comment then such $C^1$-diffeomorphism probably exists. This essentially a local question, I will have to think more about it. In any case, you do not really need this for Green's Theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070393/greens-theorem-for-piecewise-smooth-curves).